# Oracle OCIBindByPos() for out bind variables

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Is there a good document on how to bind variables by using OCI? I am having trouble with binding an **out bind** variables. buf is bound with a "OUT" variable in stored procedure.

Question 1: do I need to pre-allocate memory for `buf`? Or OCI can do that?

Question 2: is there a way to tell how many bytes of characters stored in `buf`? Or just treat it as a null-terminated C-string?

```
int pos; 
char* buf; 
size_t len;
int rc = OCIBindByPos( Stmt, &bind, errhp, pos, buf, len, SQLT_STR,
                       NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT );
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having?

Comment: Without allocate memory to buf in advance, OCI just throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: do I need to pre-allocate memory for buf? Or OCI can do that?
Yes of course you need. You need to use OCIHandle

```
OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *)OCIEnv, (dvoid **)&OCIStmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, len, 
                      (dvoid **)&buf);
```

Question 2: is there a way to tell how many bytes of characters stored in buf? Or just treat it as a null-terminated C-string?

In

```
OCIBindByPos
```

you tell how many bytes.